# How to change android notification icon to numbers in percent like battery charge

Tags: java, android, notifications, icons

how i can change android notification icon to numbers in percent like battery charge? I need to display dynamic int value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot display a dynamic value but you can illustrate a dynamic behaviour. You will have to keep images of all percents you want to display and when something changes (according to your logic) update the notification with the according image - basically you'll have to replace the existing notification with a different one.